# Upload file to Elastic Beanstalk Quellbundle

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment and ec2 instances with autoscaling. Therefore, the instances can change over time.
My source code is made available via CodePipeline via a Git repository. Now I have a file with sensitive information that I don't want to add to the repository. My question is how can I make this file available for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use one of the other AWS services. If it's a simple file, you could upload it to an S3 bucket, and provide permissions to your `InstanceProfile` which allows them to read this file. Depending on how sensitive the data is, you should also ensure that you nail down the S3 bucket policy and use S3 bucket encryption.

But if we're talking about sensitive data that you want to have available for your application (such as database connection information) you can also use AWS Secrets Manager or the AWS SSM Parameter store. These are designed specifically for this purpose. It also allows running the same code on different environments (for example in different AWS accounts) with different values in the Parameter Store / Secrets Manager. For these services, you will also have to update the permissions in the `InstanceProfile`.